# Comparing large number of big string text in SQL Server - Is Performance better if hash is compared instead of the strings

Tags: sql-server, hash, string-comparison

A particular application (ASP.Net/C# & SQL Server Express 2014) of mine has the following requirements. On a certain UI action, the following :

1. around 120+ blocks of text, each about 10,000 characters (unicode) need to be compared to another corresponding set of 120+ blocks.
2. This text block contains HTML and the actual text content is likely to be in any language.

The solution that I have in mind is to use [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) and hash all the values and keep. When it is time to compare, I would compare the hash value instead of large text block. I will hash the values once and keep (and rehash when the source value changes) and use them multiple times for comparison.

Here are my questions:

1. Is my solution optimal from a performance point?
2. Is the HASHBYTE (say SHA1 algorithm) subject to hash collision? Should I be checking the string value when I get hash match?

Comment: Given the size of your strings, `HASHBYTES` might not be a viable solution, since it [on SQL 2014 and earlier it only supports inputs of up to 8000 bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will definitely be faster to compare hashes than to compare strings.  Even if the CPU cost of comparing large strings is ignored, due to these being nvarchar(max) and 10,000 characters, they will be in the large object store (LOB storage), rather than on row, and will require additional disk IO.

As was pointed out, HASHBYTES has an 8000 byte limit.  To overcome this, you will need to break up the data into chunks that are less than 4000 characters (since they are 2 bytes each) and hash them in chunks.  The intermediate hashes can then be concatenated and the result hashed.

There is a very slight chance of a SHA1 hash collision.  If that is a concern, it is recommended to use SHA_256.  The result will be 32 bytes instead of the 20 for SHA1.

LOB Storage:
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/understanding-lob-data-20082008r2-2012/

Hash collisions:  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24732/probability-of-sha256-collisions-for-certain-amount-of-hashed-values